# Using rollsum function for future instances (forward rollsum)

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I want to apply a forward `rollsum`, i.e., instead of giving me the sum (or median) of past instances, I want to calculate the sum of future instances.

I know the function `rollsum` (and `rollmedian`, `rollapply`), but they just work for past instances. At least, I haven't been able to find information on how to do it.

Example:

```
price  = c(c5,5,8,2,6,2,6,6,6,0,7,0,3,8,9,9)    
past   = rollsum(price, 4, align='right',fill=NA)    
future = c(21,18,16,20,2018,19,13,10,18,20,29,rep(NA,4))
price past future
  5   NA     21
  5   NA     18
  8   NA     16
  2   20     20
  6   21     20
  2   18     18
  6   16     19
  6   20     13
  6   20     10
  0   18     18
  7   19     20
  0   13     29
  3   10     NA
  8   18     NA
  9   20     NA
  9   29     NA
```

Comment: Please show a small example and expected output.

Comment: `rev`erse your vector.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I think I just answered my own question. I think that more than reversing, I need to shift the vector by n places, where n is the window. I mean this for the rollsum result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could also use `roll_sum` from `library(RcppRoll)`

```
library(RcppRoll)
roll_sum(df1$price,4, align='left', fill=NA)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `align` argument controls this.  For example, by specifying `align = "left"` we get this:

```
library(zoo)

rollsum(1:6, 3, align = "left", fill = NA)
## [1]  6  9 12 15 NA NA
```

The 6 in the output is 1+2+3, the 9 in the output is 2+3+4, etc.  The last two elements are NA since there are not 3 future elements.

Even more flexiblity is available if you use to `rollapply`.  For example, this is the same as above:

```
rollapply(1:6, 3, sum, align = "left", fill = NA)
## [1]  6  9 12 15 NA NA
```

whereas the following sums the 3 components AFTER but not including the current component (the elements of the list are the offsets from the current position to use where 0 means current position, 1 is the next position, etc. -- negative numbers can be used for the prior positions).

```
rollapply(1:6, list(1:3), sum, fill = NA)
## [1]  9 12 15 NA NA NA
```

Thus 9 is 2+3+4 since 2, 3, 4 are the 3 components that come after the first component, 1.

Comment: You are totally right, and I apologize for this. I edited my question, and added an example. Thank you.

Comment: And you are right, align left does the trick. Did not see that before. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're ordering your data by date, couldn't you do something like:

```
df %>%
    group_by( someFactorColumn) %>% # optional grouping variable
    arrange(-dateItHappened) %>%
    mutate( forwardsum = cumsum( valYouCareAbout) %>%
    arrange( dateItHappened)
```